# ¿Como llenar datos de ID si nos dan los nombres, de tablas Productos y Categorias desde un listado en excel? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de crear una base de datos en sql server donde tengo las tablas `Productos`, `Categorias` y una de la relacion de productos de excel.

[Tabla Temporal](importe desde el excel)

```
Nombre Producto                                                      
Nombre Categoria
Precio   
Cant...
```

[Productos]

```
IDProducto(PK) 
NombreProducto
IDCategoria(FK)
```

[Categorias]

```
IDCategoria(PK)
NombreCategoria
```

He podido llenar la tabla `categorias` y tengo 120 categorías distintas; en el listado de Excel tengo una relación de 10000 productos; las categorías tiene varios productos.

El problema es que no se como insertar los productos con un `IDCategoria` y no con el nombre de la categoría

Lista de productos Excel:
[image: lista productos Excel]

Comment: ¿Tienes ya todo en SQL Server? Sugiero que incluyas dentro de tu pregunta el código de cómo estás llenando la tabla de categorías, para que la respuesta que recibas vaya por la misma línea. Un saludo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Importaste esta tabla asi como esta? si es asi, solo tenes que hacer un query de transformacion.. Quiero supoer que tu tabla producto saco los nombres de este excel, y el de categorias tambien no? si es asi, se puede resolver el query, pero aclaralo.

Comment: La que importe es [Tabla Temporal];
Luego hice un INSERT a tabla [Categorias], y me genera un ID numerico de 1 a 120 categorias.
Pero no se como hacer el INSERT para llenar la Tabla[Productos] y que en el campo IDCategoria(forean key de tabla[Categorias]) se llene xq ejempo si dice bebidas ID = 1, Condimentos ID = 2, ....ID = 120;  y no se como hacerlo

Comment: el codigo insert para tabla [Categorias] fue: INSERT INTO Categorias SELECT T.Nombre_Categoria FROM [Tabla Temporal] as T. Al ser clave Identiad me genera IDs de 1 - 120

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi tu problema, esta sería la forma más tediosa de hacerlo:

Creas las tablas

```
CREATE TABLE Productos(
    IDProducto INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NombreProducto VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    IDCategoria INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDProducto),
    FOREIGN KEY (IDCategoria) REFERENCES Categorias(IDCategoria)
);

CREATE TABLE Categorias(
    IDCategoria INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NombreCategoria VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDCategoria)       
);
```

Insertas datos a tu catálogo Categorías:

```
INSERT INTO Categorias (NombreCategoria) VALUES ('Carnes');
INSERT INTO Categorias (NombreCategoria) VALUES ('Bebidas');
```

Vez que ids fueron los insertados para colocarlos en la FK en la tabla Productos:

```
SELECT * FROM Categorias;
```

Finalmente haces los inserts en tu tabla Productos:

```
INSERT INTO Productos (NombreProducto, IDCategoria) VALUES('Buey', 1);
INSERT INTO Productos (NombreProducto, IDCategoria) VALUES('Cerveza', 2);
```

Comment: :(  eso no quiero hacer xq son 120 categorias y no quisiera pasarme el dia copiando los nombres e ID